# Most efficient way to update related Model from event listener

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models `Business` and `Products`.

I have an event which fires whenever the price of a product changes, an event listener will calculate the min and max aggregate values of the businesses products and store them within the Business model (while I know this can be done dynamically, this is required for indexing and searches).

In my event listener handle I have the following:

```
public function handle(ProductModified $event)
{
    $business = $event->product->business;

    $aggregate_values = Product::join('business', 'product.business_id', '=', 'business.id')->where('business.business_id', '=', $business->id)->groupBy('business.business_id')->get(['product.business_id', DB::raw('max(product.price) as max_cost, min(product.price) as min_cost')]);

    Log::info('aggregate values: ' . $aggregate_values);

    $business->min_cost = $aggregate_values->min_cost;
    $business->max_cost = $aggregate_values->max_cost;
    $business->update;

}
```

Using the code above I receive the following error:

> Property [min_cost] does not exist on this collection instance.

My understanding is that I'll have to do a Business:find() to initiate the model and then update it. Is yes, is there a more efficient way to do this as this will call another query? Otherwise could someone tell me the correct way to update the related model?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Query return Laravel Collection object instead Product Model object. In order to fetch property, you can simply use `$aggregate_values->first()->min_cost`

If it won't work, you can replace query with this one

```
$result = Product::select('product.business_id', DB::raw('max(product.price) as max_cost, min(product.price) as min_cost'))->join('business', 'product.business_id', '=', 'business.id')->where('business.business_id', '=', $business->id)->groupBy('business.business_id')->firstOrFail();
$business->min_cost = $result->min_cost;
$business->max_cost = $result->max_cost;
$business->save();
```

Most efficient way to update related model is by using Eloquent Relationship feature [Documentation url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)